# How to add JSON file export functionality in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

So i am interested in writing a method that when i click an export button, certain data from the db at exported to JSON data.

How can i do that?

The procedure is this

```
get data from db -> convert to json -> write to file -> save file to computer.
```

thanks

Comment: See [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)

Comment: thanks but i need a mockup of the whole procedure because i am kind of new to all this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use *to_json* method, *send_data* with disposition header:

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def users_json
    data = User.all.to_json
    send_data data, :type => 'application/json; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=users.json"
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you but the output is ugly, how can i beautify it and have a correct structure? it tried with pretty_generate method but i get this error "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed"

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou the representation is browser domain, please try browser's plugin, for instance: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/

Comment: i've installed it on Chrome but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou not sure if Firefox plugin would work on Chrome... Try [similar plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) but for Chrome instead

Comment: erm its the same extension i used, JSONView for Chrome, and its not opening the json file as soon as i hit the export button. the browser downloads the file instead. Are there any extra steps to the code above?

Comment: As I understood you correctly, *write to file -> save file to computer.* then open file from browser and read JSON nicely is what you exactly need. If requirements changed, take out *disposition* header or even *send_data* and just do *render :json => data*

Comment: so for the JSONView extension to work i have to assign json files to the browser application?

Comment: to let JSONView or similar plugins, you need to serve a response with MIME TYPE: *application/json* which is automatically provided by *render :json => data*

Comment: In your snippet above i can see applications/json is it not the same?